# Redactor js editor and Bootstrap 3

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, redactor

I bought the Redactor HTML5 editor component (V9) and have been working with it all day. I've been using CKeditor for years. But it's just not usable with HTML5. It keeps stripping out elements and rewriting the code.

The editor needs to be able to cope with HTML5 and Bootstrap 3 markup.

Redactor looks great on the surface. But after spending time with it, it's still not that powerful. Yes I know it can upload images. But applying DIVs and CSS seems to be a pretty raw experience.

I spent a few hours trying to build a custom button to add DIVs and classes. But why do I need to do so much work. I don't want to write an editor.

It has nice documentation, but it's still pretty thin. More examples would really help.

e.g. I'd like to get the CSS to apply to the live editor (like CKeditor can do) But I'd also like to keep it to replacing textares rather than resorting to an iframe.

I'd also like to be able to see the hidden divs in the editor. Otherwise the user gets lost and will destroy the layout.

Has anyone come across online resources that help the situation? Or should I just tell my client we need to go back to hand coding the layouts?

Comment: Post some of your code you have so far, maybe there's an easier way.

Comment: Gave up and returned it for refund. Nice little editor but not powerful enough for what I need. I'm fighting through TinyMCE 4 now. I suspect it will do the trick. Not the best HTML source mode though.